# Yii 2 Advanced template default backend admin login details

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I followed this tutorial https://yii2-framework.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/tutorial-advanced-app/ but it doesn't say anything about backend admin login details.

How to setup backend admin login details?

Comment: look [here](http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/yii-2-user-login-from-database/) it will help you understand the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install and MIGRATE RBAC extension, after that register user with username admin. Take his `id` from DB and follow this tutorial:
https://habr.com/ru/post/235485/
 how to set up role based access. I guess that's what you trying to implement.

Comment: Tx that is what I needed to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Yii2 templates basically is a starting point to develop an app, not a pre-made cms that has default logins.

In this case, if you have executed migrations as outlined in the tutorial

> 3. Apply migrations with console command yii migrate.

Then you would have a user table in your database. You could create a new user there with a [bcrypted](https://www.browserling.com/tools/bcrypt) password, and then use that to login to the application.